# How do you control what's under the "User's Files" folder on the Desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, group-policy, user-profiles

On a Windows 10 user's Desktop, there is a folder that can be displayed which is a representation of the user's special/known folders.  It looks similar to `%userprofile%`, but I don't think it's the same thing.  The only reference I can find is:  "User's Files" (Themes and Related Settings >> check User's Files)

My expectation is that this folder should exactly match the user's "known folders". That is, I'd expect special folders to show here, and they all ought to point to the actual physical location of those folders, regardless if they've been relocated to OneDrive, or some other drive.

"User's Files" does NOT display all the content of `%userprofile%`, even with "show hidden files" checked.  Furthermore, the folders here are not representative of the "actual" folders (if OneDrive has taken over, for example).

So, what is the purpose of the "User's Files" icon, and how is it being populated? Is this a junction point?  How do I modify it, and where do I find the configuration for this view?  Is that in the registry?  Why can't I customize it?

[image]

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to identify how the "User's Files" folder on the Desktop is being populated.  I'm trying to identify the mechanism that populates the folders which are visible there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That folder is a virtual folder that displays the contents of your UserProfile folder (c:\Users<XXX>) as well as redirected User Shell Folders provided they're not redirected to another User Shell Folder, which is the case with folders redirected to **OneDrive**.

It's defined in the registry here:

```
>gi 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{f3ce0f7c-4901-4acc-8648-d5d44b04ef8f}' | ft -AutoSize


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDe
    scriptions


Name                                   Property
----                                   --------
{f3ce0f7c-4901-4acc-8648-d5d44b04ef8f} Category    : 1
                                       Name        : UsersFilesFolder
                                       ParsingName :
                                       ::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}
```

Note the `Properties` of the `Documents` folder in your screenshot has no `Location` tab --- because it is no longer the target of a shell folder --- it's only displaying because it's an ordinary file folder in your UserProfile folder --- you could delete it if your wanted.

If `Pictures` & `Desktop` were redirected to another drive, or even a folder at the root of C:, they would appear.

A while back, I decided to move Screenshots out of Pictures because I didn't want those images cluttering up the Photos app. So I redirected the Screenshots folder to a folder of the same name under my UserProfile folder. I could see the ordinary folder I'd created under the `UsersFilesFolder`, but it disappeared when I made it the "official" `Screenshots` folder.

The problem turned out to be the `'ParentFolder'` value for the `Screenshots` folder was specified as the `Pictures` folder. I disabled that value by renaming it to "xParentFolder" and then it appeared.

Though I try to avoid editing entries under `HKLM`, there was no other way to accomplish this.

I don't even think the same trick will work in your case because the folders are still actually under **OneDrive.**

Comment: This is the level of detail and understanding I was seeking.  Thank you for explaining what is happening.